# October CMS : Not able to create a Form Widget

Tags: php, octobercms

I'm new to October CMS and learning to create a Form Widget. But I'm getting the following error :

```
The partial '_field_actorbox.htm' is not found.
/opt/lampp/htdocs/octobermovies/modules/system/traits/ViewMaker.php line 65
```

My widget folder name is 'formwidgets' 
My partials file name inside partials folder is '_widget.htm' 
Content of my formwidgets > Actorbox.php

```
namespace Watchlearn\Movies\FormWidgets;

use Backend\Classes\FormWidgetBase;
use Config;

class ActorBox extends FormWidgetBase
{
    public function widgetDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Actorbox',
            'description' => 'Field for adding actors'
        ];
    }

    public function render(){
        return $this->makePartial('widget');
    }

    public function loadAssets()
    {
        $this->addCss('css/select2.css');
        $this->addJs('js/select2.js');
    }
}
```

My code to register the widget in plugin.php

```
public function registerFormWidgets()
    {
        return [
            'Watchlearn\Movies\FormWidgets\ActorBox' => [
                'label' => 'ActorBox Field',
                'code' => 'actorbox'
            ]
        ];
    }
```

I tried to find and looked into the documentation also but could not find any solution for this.

Comment: Use a _block comment_ (precede contents with `> `) for longish quotes/error messages.

Comment: @greybeard thank you for your suggestion. Do you have something to solve the problem I posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Actorbox.php should be in the formwidgets path. If properly created the dir structure would be like

```
|-- formwidgets
|  
|-- ActorBox.php
|   `-- actorbox
|       |-- assets
|       |   |-- css
|       |   |   |-- actorbox.css
|       |   |   `-- select2.min.css
|       |   `-- js
|       |       |-- actorbox.js
|       |       `-- select2.min.js
|       `-- partials
|           `-- _actorbox.htm
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I had the form widget file it in the widget's name subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

did you created your formwidget files using artisan ?

`php artisan create:formwidget watchlearn\Movies Tagbox` (into the plugin folder)

Maybe it will help you set the correct permissions and help you out :)
(it did for me, I had exactly the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error lies here:

> My widget folder name is 'formwidgets' My partials file name inside partials folder is '_widget.htm' Content of my formwidgets > **Actorbox.php**

But then you have

> class **ActorBox** extends FormWidgetBase

and you seem to use that classname with the uppercase B throughout the rest of the code.

OctoberCMS is looking for the file **formWidgets/ActorBox.php**, matching the classname given in the **registerFormWidgets** function. FormWidget (and Component and Model and etc.) .php file names should always match the contained Widget (or whatever the case) class names *with the exact same case*.

So in this case, the form widget is simply not registered, because no file with the matching name is found. The field of `type: actorbox` in the form definition .yaml file you are using is then by default causing October to look for a `_field_actorbox.htm` partial to be rendered.

So just rename your **Actorbox.php** to **ActorBox.php** and your problem should be solved, I hope.

Comment: Yup, the file name is not october compliant. The filename needs to be the exact match to the classname. https://octobercms.com/help/guidelines/developer#class-naming

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your path of your file actorbox.php. I got the same issues as well, I moved my actorbox.php to the correct path then everything works fine.